# Please teach me how to optimize this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, primary-key

I have two tables, `main_part` (3k records) and `part_details` (25k records)

I tried the following indexes but `explain` always returns full table scan of 25k records as opposed to about 2k of matched records and `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`

```
ALTER TABLE `main_part` ADD INDEX `main_part_index_1` (`unit`);
ALTER TABLE `part_details` ADD INDEX `part_details_index_1` (`approved`, `display`, `country`, `id`, `price`);
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT a.part_id, b.my_title, 
       b.price, a.type, 
       a.unit, a.certification, 
       b.my_image, 
       b.price/a.unit AS priceW 
FROM main_part AS a
INNER JOIN part_details AS b ON a.part_id=b.id
WHERE b.approved = 'Yes' 
AND b.display = 'On' 
AND b.country = 'US' 
AND a.unit >= 300 
ORDER BY b.price ASC LIMIT 50
```

One thing that I am aware of is that a.part_id is not a Primary Key in main_part table. Could this be a culprit?

Create tables SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_part` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `part_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `unit` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `certification` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `part_details` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `asn` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `my_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `display` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'On',
  `approved` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `price` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `my_image` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `update_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `countryasn` (`country`,`asn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Show us create table DDL.

Comment: If you want to learn check:  MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Would it matter if a.unit is not an integer? It is declared as a varchar(50).  You check where a.unit >= 300 which would be some sort of integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your query the more important index is the `JOIN` condition and as you are already aware `a.part_id` isn't primary key, so doesn't have a default index and your first try should be:

```
ALTER TABLE `main_part` ADD INDEX `main_part_index_1` (`part_id`,`unit`);
```

Because we are interested on the `JOIN` condition first you should also change the second index to

```
ALTER TABLE `part_details` ADD INDEX `part_details_index_1` 
            (`id`, `approved`, `display`, `country`, `price`);
```

*order matters in the index*

Another tip is you start with the basic query:

```
SELECT *
FROM main_part AS a
INNER JOIN part_details AS b ON a.part_id=b.id
```

Add index for `part_id` and `id` check the explain plan and then start adding condition and updating the index if required.

Comment: Should the first index be on `part_id, unit` ? As `a.id <> b.id`. Those are just auto increment columns for each table. Actual match would be `a.part_id=b.id`

Comment: You are right. I assume you were join on the main id. That is why I dont like use just `id`  as a name can be confusing what id you are referring too.

Comment: Just tried and the results still the same. All rows were scanned using `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`

Comment: index tuning is more art than science. As I said you start with the base query and build it up.

Comment: But shouldn't explain on the simple query shows `rows` only for matched records in scan? `explain SELECT * FROM main_part AS a INNER JOIN part_details AS b ON a.part_id=b.id WHERE a.unit >= 300`

Comment: are you using index `(part_id,unit)` for that? how many rows are with unit >=300 ?

Comment: Yes, I am using `(part_id,unit)` and there are ~3k records for `a.unit >= 300`. Explain command on that query shows `rows` at ~25k

Comment: But again, do I make b.part_id as a primary key? It is not primary now

Comment: doesnt matter. the important part is the index. If you remove the >= 300 condition use the index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159597/discussion-between-myroslav-tedoski-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that most columns used for filtering in part_details aren't very selective (display is probably an On/off switch, country is probably very similar in many products, etc.).

In some cases, when the WHERE clause is not very selective, MySQL may choose to use an index that better suits the ORDER BY clause.

I would try to create this index as well and check in the explain plan if there is any changes:

```
ALTER TABLE `part_details` ADD INDEX `part_details_price_index` (`price`);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT mp.part_id, pd.my_title, pd.price, mp.type, 
       mp.unit, mp.certification, pd.my_image, 
       pd.price/mp.unit AS priceW 
FROM main_part mp INNER JOIN
     part_details pd
     ON mp.part_id = pd.id
WHERE pd.approved = 'Yes' AND
      pd.display = 'On' AND
      pd.country = 'US' AND
      mp.unit >= 300 
ORDER BY pd.price ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

For this query, I would start with indexes on `part_details(country, display, approved, id, price)` and `main_part(part_id, unit)`.

The index on `part_details` can be used for filtering before the `join`.  It is not easy to get rid of the sort for the `order by`.

Comment: Tried your suggestions. Still getting my original results. Problem here is that a peasant with a hammer is trying to fine tune a violin...